# HubSpot API — Automatically bulk delete tasks/contacts/deals (or anything) using Make

Tags: hubspot, make.com

I would like to **automatically bulk delete** all tasks older than a month in HubSpot (we have more than 10,000 tasks!), instead of doing it one by one. I tried looking on the [internet](https://community.hubspot.com/t5/CRM/Hubspot-automatically-delete-task-associated-with-contacts-that/td-p/670664) but it doesn’t seem that HubSpot has any functionalities like it. Thus, I tried to implement such scenario using Make (formerly Integromat) unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering to my question for knowledge purposes.**

I managed to create a scenario allowing me to automatically bulk delete tasks (or anything) based on a certain set of criteria using Make (formerly Integromat). I had to use HubSpot’s API and Flow Control tools to achieve such result.

The scenario looks like the following:
[image: Automatically bulk delete all tasks in HubSpot using a Make scenario overview]

### Module 1: API Call

Search for all tasks based on a certain set of criteria (here, all tasks created before the last 30 days).

*If you wish to search for another object (such as contacts or deals), you can take a look at the [CRM Search API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search) for all available search requests. You can also browse through the [Properties API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/properties) to get a comprehensive list of available properties.*

- URL: `/crm/v3/objects/tasks/search`
- Method: `POST`
- Body:

```
    {
      "limit": "5",
      "properties": [
        "hs_task_subject",
        "hs_task_type",
        "hs_timestamp"
      ],
      "filterGroups": [
        {
          "filters": [
            {
              "propertyName": "hs_task_status",
              "operator": "EQ",
              "value": "NOT_STARTED"
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "hs_createdate",
              "operator": "LT",
              "value": "{{formatDate(addDays(now; -30); "x")}}"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

### Module 2: Repeater

- Initial Value: `0`
- Repeats: `{{if(module1.body.total = null; 1; module1.body.total / 100)}}` (if total is less than 100, do not repeat)
- Step: `{{ifempty(module1.body.paging.next.after; 100)}}` (automatically sets it to the first module’s `after` value, otherwise to 100 if `after` value is empty)

You can find out more about properties and search limitations [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search#limitations) and [here](https://For%20example,%20the%20request%20below%20would%20return%20the%20next%20page%20of%20results:). Basically, the repeater allows you to loop over all HubSpot pages.

### Module 3: Sleep

Sleep module to prevent `RateLimitError`

### Module 4: API Call

Same as Module 1, except that you must add an `after` parameter to include the repeater’s value.

```
+    "after": "{{module2.i}}"
```

### Module 5: Iterator

Iterate over Module 4’s results array: `{{module4.body.results}}`.

### Module 6: API Call

Delete tasks using the ID returned by the iterator.

```
{
   "inputs":[
      {
         "id":"{{module5.id}}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Voilà !